# How to implement scalar operation of all elements of matrix in Metal Performance Shaders?

Tags: metal, metal-performance-shaders

Let's say I have a matrix, and I want to compute sin() on all elements.

How do I do that with metal performance shaders?

Do I write some new kernel inheriting from `MPSMatrixUnaryKernel`?

Comment: If you can provide that as an answer, I can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think MPS is not meant to be extended. You can "simply" write your own Metal compute shader for that.

[This](http://metalkit.org/2019/01/31/intro-to-metal-compute.html) seems to be a good tutorial to get started.